# Trying to get along with Interwoven

Tags: content-management-system, teamsite, interwoven

I am to create a new design (CSS & HTML) for a web site which is created using Interwoven ContentCenter Professional.

Now, I can see the existing files in CMS (Interwoven) but, I can't make changes. My changes are displayed only when I'm in edit mode. Nothing in the live page. I tried to submit, create editions of files but still no good.

How should I create or edit pages in Interwoven CMS?

[image: A screen-shot of what i see]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about generic pages, then once you are finished you have to click on the `Generate` option, then choose a directory and click `Finish`. Last thing you should do is to choose `yes`when it asks you to `Re-generate` the page.

Comment: Hi. I created a page using the menu File > New File. Edited, saved, uploaded and unlocked it. Then selected it and after that clicked the item Actions > Generate page. But it gives an error: Invalid form entry

Comment: Weird, doesn't seem to be a message from the CMS itself.

Comment: I'm a newbie to the whole concept. So I've uploaded a screen-shot in main post. Please check it out to see if I'm speaking about the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is just creating a new file, not generating a file from TeamSite's Formpublisher.  It is just like if you are in Windows Explorer and creating a new file.  In order to generate a file from a form entry, you need to be in the templatedata directory, ex: /default/main/branch1/WORKAREA/wa1/templatedata/category/type(on unix) or Y:/default/main/branch1/WORKAREA/wa1/templatedata/category/type (on Windows). There should be a file call datacapture.cfg there.  There is another directory called data under the above path which stores your data content record (dcr) that are created from the form.  This is the file that you can use to generate which will use the (tpl) file under the presentation directory.